# The boundary of a Ball in a Vector space equals the Sphere?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $(V, \Vert.\Vert)$ be a normed Vector space, $v_0 \in V$ and $r > 0$ and consider the Sphere:

$$S(v_0, r) = \{v\in V : \Vert v- v_0\Vert = r   \}$$

is $\delta B_V(v_0, r) = S(v_0, r)$  ?

where $B_V(v_0,r) = \{v \in V : \Vert v-v_o\Vert < r \}$

and the boundary $\delta$ of $A$ as: $\delta A = cl_V(A) / int(A)$

where $cl_V(A)$ is the closure of $A$ and $int(A)$ is the interior of $A$.

I also know that $cl_V(B_V(v_0,r)) = \overline B_V(v_0,r) $ because is a Vector Space.

where $\overline B_V(v_0,r) = \{v \in V : \Vert v-v_o\Vert \le r \}$.

I guess I have to proove that $int(B_V(v_0,r)) = B_V(v_0,r)$

Comment: What is your *definition* of $\delta B_V(v_0,r)$? Presumably you mean $B_V(v_0,r)=\{v\in V: \|v-v_0\|\le r\}$. Then, yes, its boundary is $S(v_0,r)$. If you are looking for a *proof* of this fact, then you need to give your definition of "boundary".

Comment: What did you try to solve this problem?

Comment: I edited the question. And $B_V(v_o,r) = \{ v \in V : \Vert v- v_o\Vert <r \}$. Also added info of what I know and what a Ithink I have to do, unless there is other way around.

Comment: You mean \setminus, not / .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've tagged this [general-topology](/questions/tagged/general-topology), you would know that the (strong) topology on a normed linear space is defined by a basis of open balls (maybe you turn $V$ into a metric space first, but either way, the topology is defined in this way). This means that open balls like $B_V(v_0, r)$ are open **by definition of the topology**. Also, note that open sets are trivially equal to their own interiors (interiors are the largest open set contained in the given set). After that, apply your own logic, and you are done.

Comment: Sorry. I removed the tag.

Comment: @Alejo No worries; I thought this answer would help you, but I'm fine to delete it. You should put, into your question, what your definition of "open" and "interior" are, so that others don't make the same error.

Comment: I removed the tag. Nontheless you are right. The open Ball has to be equal to its own interior... if that's what I understand... That's what I need. But, excuse me, is it really trivial? Is there a proof for that?

Comment: You are right. Sorry. now I get it reading twice your comment haha. The Interior is the largest open set contained in a given set, but the Ball is open, therefore the Ball is contained in the interior, and at the same time the interior is contained in the Ball. Therefore they are equal!